# Running maven project from command line take too much time

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

When I run and deploy a java/maven project (REST Webserver) from eclipse it take few seconds to deploy, but when I run it from the command line, I have to wait about 5 minutes. Do you have an idea what the problem is ? I use this command to build and deploy the project

```
mvn clean verify org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:run
```

Comment: Do you have lots of tests in the project? They are probably not run during an eclipse build.

Comment: are you using the same version of Maven in eclipse and in command line? Are you specifying the same string at both the places?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the same Maven instance in eclipse and using the command line. I think that you are using an embedded version of maven in eclipse and using the command line, it had to download all the dependencies another time.